# How to set Cookie in urllib2 manually?

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I am using python urllib2 to download web pages. But there is a problem that confused me. I want to set a cookie, but I do not know exactly how to do it. Can I just use CookieJar, or some other way can be tried to solve my problem. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
def http_get(uri, params, previous_url):
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    opener.handle_open["http"][0].set_http_debuglevel(1)
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36'
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','RT=Some Values'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('User-Agent', user_agent))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', previous_url))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Accept', '*/*'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'))
    url_values = urllib.urlencode(params)
    request_uri = uri + '?' + url_values    
    request = urllib2.Request(request_uri)
    response = opener.open(request_uri)
    return response, request_uri
```

I do not know where is wrong, please help!

Comment: You have `.append(('Cookie', ...`. in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did your code works?I think you don't have to use CookieJar.Usually the code should be:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'RT=Some Values'))
#request_uri = ......
response = opener.open(request_uri)
print response.read()
```